# Video and Text on carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, video

I'm working on a project and I'm trying o figure out how this company http://weareroyale.com manages to execute the video banner on their homepage...

I Can see theres an animation and I can see the text seems to come in using transparent PNGs, but I can't seem to work out how they get the timing right?

I mean, the text comes up on specific parts of the video, but how do they get the timing right? I would have thought that it would be quicker to load the PNGs than the video to start, I guess you could allow for this but it would also be different loading speeds for every user...

So, Im wondering if anyone knows how it's been created? Is it a slider addon? Created from Scratch? etc etc?

Comment: `video.currentTime` and `svg`'s

Comment: Thanks @avrilalejandro - So is this JavaScript? I guessing then,  if that function can keep track of the time of a video, then we can create actions to fire in certain time stamps, changing divs (or PNGs) from display:none; as and when we want them to show - would that be correct?

Comment: Would you happen to know any good resources for learning about this? :)

Comment: yep. only JS... https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_text.asp www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/#toc-jsprop

Comment: Thanks a lot @avrilalejandro if you want to put it as an answer I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video');
//video.load();
video.play();
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
  if (this.currentTime >= 2.000 && this.currentTime <= 8.000){
    this.pause();
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML=this.duration;
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<video width="400" id="video" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
<p id="text"></p>
```